# Print all the prime numbers between 101 and 200 using while loop

Tags: java

When I run the program below there is no output and the program doesn't quit. It should print the primes. The program is required to be run using while loops. Where does it go wrong?

```
public class F {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int a = 101, b = 200, c = 2;

        while (a <= b) {
            while (a > c) {
                c = 2;
                if (a % c == 0) {
                    c = 200;
                } else if (a == c) {
                    System.out.println(a);
                } else {
                    c++;
                }
            }
            a++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Comment: See also [homework guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: `while (a > c)` will never terminate when a = 101, and c will either be 2 (first iteration) or 3 (second and subsequent iterations), `a % c ==0 ` and `a == c` are always false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some issues with the original code:

- always increment `c`
- reset `c` outside inner while loop
- code will never print a prime because the order of conditions is wrong. if `a == c` is valid, so is `a % c == 0`
- inner while loop needs to permit `a == c`

Code with fixes:

```
public class F {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int a = 101, b = 200, c = 2;

        while (a <= b) {
            c = 2;         
            while (a >= c) {
                if (a == c) {
                    System.out.println(a);
                } else if (a % c == 0) {
                    c = 200;
                }
                c++;
            }
            a++;
        }
    }
}
```